# How to get result value of correlation function after matchTemplate openCV?

Tags: java, opencv

I use openCV to find a part of an image in another one. And then I need to plot a graph containing values of correlation function in every point of image.
I only know how to get min and max value and its location(eg mmr.maxVal).

Here are main functions that I use.

```
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(myimg, mytempl, result, method);
        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
```

Comment: _a graph containing values of correlation function in every point of image_. This is exactly what `result` is. What's the issue with that?

Comment: @Miki 
I've tried result.get(y,x), but the range of values is incorrect. For example, for normalized cross-correlation(NCC) function it must be from 0 to 1 (in general from -1 to 1), but using this function I have values only from 0,8 to 1 (approx.). And I'm looking for another solution :(